# C Programming: Using struct Accessing an array within an array during a for loop

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop, struct

I am having trouble making this function complete, mainly once i get to the for loop and try to access the x and y coordinate within the array to calculate the distance between the two.

there is a structure involved called locations_t with fields

x_loc and y_loc and my locations array looks like

```
locations[0] = {{0, 0}};
```

so the program looks to return the following output but does so to find the the locations[i] that is the min_dist from the starting value.

```
query_loc = 10, 7
locations[0] = {{10, 10}} //distance between the two is 3

query_loc = 10, 7
locations[1] = {{9, 7}} // distance between is 1

// nearest would return locations[1]
```

this is my code

```
int location_nearest (location_t query_loc, location_t locations[], int num_locations)
{
   //  (Task 5.1) If num_locations equal to or less than 0, return NULL.
    if(num_locations <= 0)
    {
    return NULL;
    }
    //  (Task 5.2) Declare and initialise a pointer to location_t called nearest.
    //  The initial value is the address of the first element in the array.
    location_t *nearest = &locations[0];

    //  (Task 5.3) Declare and initialise an integer called min_dist.
    //  The initial value is the city block distance from the query to
    //  the first element of the array.
    //  Hint: use location_dist.
    int min_dist = location_dist(query_loc, locations[0]);

    //  (Task 5.4) Set up   a for loop to iterate over the array.
    //  Skip the first element of the array, because we already know
    //  the distance from the first element to the query.
    for(int i = 1; i < num_locations; i++)
    {
        //  (Task 5.4.1) Compute the city block distance from the query
        //  to the current element of the array. This is the current
        //  distance. Make sure you remember it somehow.
        int dist = (query_loc.x_loc - locations[i][0]) + (query_loc.y_loc - locations[i][1]);
        //  (Task 5.4.2) If the current distance is less than min_dist:
        if(dist < min_dist)
        {
            //  (Task 5.4.3) Overwrite min_dist with the current distance.
            //  Overwrite nearest with the address of the current element of
            //  the array.
            min_dist = dist;
            nearest = &locations[i]
        }
    }

    //  (Task 5.5) Return nearest.
    return nearest;
}
```

Comment: Could you indicate what goes wrong? Incorrect answer, not compiling, segmentation fault, ...? Also, could you complete your code by creating a [mcve]?

Comment: Why are you using a call to `location_dist` the first time, but do the actual (one-liner) calculation inside the loop?

Comment: int dist = (query_loc.x_loc - locations[i][0]) + (query_loc.y_loc - locations[i][1]);

Comment: locations[i][0] comes up with expression must have pointer-to-object type

Comment: but your right. i should just be able to call that function

Comment: Re `locations[i][0]`: try `locations[i].x_loc` instead (similar for [1] replaced by .y_loc).

Comment: You probably want to use `abs(...)` when calculating your distances, otherwise you'll get negative distances, and those will then be regarded as nearest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do  `locations[i][0]` like this you are treating `locations`  variable as two dimensional array and it will not access the first member of structure.

In order to access `structure`  members you can  use,

> `dot(.)` operator for non pointer variable or `arrow(->)` operator for
>   pointer variable followed by member name.

Like below.

```
  int dist = (query_loc.x_loc - locations[i].x_loc) + (query_loc.y_loc - locations[i].y_loc);
```

Instead of

> ```
> int dist = (query_loc.x_loc - locations[i][0]) + (query_loc.y_loc - locations[i][1]);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one problem:

```
int location_nearest (
^^^
Return type int


location_t *nearest 
^^^^^^^^^^^
nearest is a pointer


return nearest;
       ^^^^^^^
       wrong return type
```

Comment: @Malkeir If you want to return the pointer: `int location_nearest (
` ==> `location_t * location_nearest (
`